Azure Update Manager for Linux VM fails - error processing package base-files (--configure):
I'm using Azure Update Manager to update my Linux VM. I've not done anything manually. Spent months to automatically my Linux image but with not luck.
Went to Azure Portal-> Azure Update Manager -> Select my VM -> and click install update.
An error occurs as the following.
Package failed to install: python3.10 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6).
Error code: 100
Command used: sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive LANG=en_US.UTF8 apt-get -y --only-upgrade true install python3.10=3.10.12-1~22.04.6 libpython3.10=3.10.12-1~22.04.6 libpython3.10-stdlib=3.10.12-1~22.04.6 python3.10-minimal=3.10.12-1~22.04.6 libpython3.10-minimal=3.10.12-1~22.04.6

Command output:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

The following packages will be upgraded:
    libpython3.10 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib python3.10 python3.10-minimal

5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 58 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 0 B/7,379 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Setting up base-files (12ubuntu4.7) ...
Configuration file '/etc/issue' modified since installation.
Package distributor has shipped an updated version.

What would you like to do about it?
Your options are: 
    Y or I: install the package maintainer's version
    N or O: keep your currently-installed version
    D: show the differences between the versions
    Z: start a shell to examine the situation

dpkg: error processing package base-files (--configure):
end of file on stdin at conffile prompt

Errors were encountered while processing: base-files
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I didn't find any documentation on Microsoft website. Would you please give any hint on how to solve it ?

To ensure noninteractive updates work in the future, edit the APT configuration file.

The error you’re encountering occurs because of the dpkg process is prompting for input to decide what to do about a configuration file conflict, but the DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive setting is preventing it from accepting input.
Manually configure the conflicting package by running the below command to address the package issue
sudo dpkg --configure -a

now retry the update process, it will work
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y

and to avoid similar issues in the future, modify the DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive behavior to handle configuration file conflicts automatically. As I mentioned in the comment section, edit the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90force-conf
and add this
Dpkg::Options {
    "--force-confdef";
    "--force-confold";
};


You won't get the linux fix on MS website, except these three-

Troubleshoot issues with Azure Update Manager
Troubleshoot Update Management issues
Update on Azure Linux VM fails


Thank you. When i run sudo dpkg --configure -a it shows there is an issue with lock because another process is running.

identify the existing running process- sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock and kill it sudo kill -9 <PID> to clear and remove the lock file sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend . After stopping the locking process reconfigure dpkg sudo dpkg --configure -a and install the dependency sudo apt-get install -f
. Refer- https://askubuntu.com/questions/498102/how-do-i-unlock-var-lib-dpkg-lock
